# Inserting JS player through DOM fails

Tags: javascript, dom

I have used JavaScript media players in the past, mostly *Video.js*. Commonly, to get a video player on a page I would use this:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js"></script>           
<video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-16-9" ...>
    <source src="https://.../video.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"/>
</video>
```

I now have a situation where a JavaScript function first needs to run on my page to identify what media URL should be played. I make a call to the API, and when it returns, I try the following:

```
const app = document.getElementById('root')
var embedContents = "<link href=\"https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
embedContents = embedContents + "<script src=\"https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js\"></script>"
embedContents = embedContents + "<video id=\"my-video\" class=\"video-js vjs-16-9\" ...><source src=\""
embedContents = embedContents + myURL
embedContents = embedContents + "\" type=\"application/x-mpegURL\"/></video>"
    
const embed = document.createElement('div')
embed.innerHTML = embedContents
app.appendChild(embed)
```

Forgive me if this is not the right way, I'm pretty new to JavaScript. Once this runs, all I get is a black box on the page, the player doesn't actually load. From the debugging I've done, it appears that the scripts are being fetched. I've also tried putting the `link` and `script` tags in the `<head>` of my HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to import the script in a more specific way, like so:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.7.6/video.js"
app.appendChild(firstScript)
```

Then I used the rest of the `div` element as before.